# How to load 2 modules in Apache (Python & PHP)

Tags: php, python, apache, apache-config

I already have Django setup for use on a Windows machine. I now want to setup PHP on it as well. I have Django working with Apache 2.4 and mod_wsgi. I need Apache to load 2 modules: mod_wsgi (already works) and php5apache2_4.dll (for PHP). To say the least, the PHP module doesn't load.

Here is my httpd.conf file:

```
    LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
    LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

    # configure the path to php.ini
    PHPIniDir "C:/php"

    AddModule mod_php5.c
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Apache does not load when **BOTH** modules are running.
What am I missing and is this possible?

I want to use this to develop both PHP and Python projects on the same machine using APACHE for both.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is there anything of internest in the debug log?

Comment: The .so in mod_wsgi.so implies a *nix operating system.  The .dll in php5apache2_4.dll implies a Windows operating system.  What opsys are you actually running?

Comment: Running win7. The .so is running fine. The log has nothing of interest.

Comment: I think I got it down now. It appears that Visual Studio compiler versions really do matter. All very picky! https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst

Comment: This should be really followed closely, but it makes a lot of sense.